# How to manage multiple projects in git with different emails?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I have a project in GitHub working with git config:

```
git config --global user.email = "abc@gmail.com"
git config --global user.name = "abc"
```

Now I need to host another project in git lab, with different email id:

```
my email account is "xyz@gmail.com"
```

Do I need to configure anything in git bash, what is the steps I need to do?

If I tried using the same account, I afraid some issue occur

also i got this error

Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

can anyone help me on this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your new repo, all you need to do is, in the repo folder, to do:

```
git config user.email xyz@gmail.com
# or
git config --replace-all user.email xyz@gmail.com
```

The local configuration will override the global one, and your commits will have the right email.

Note: this has nothing to do with the authentication on GitLab.

As [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40124473/how-to-manage-multiple-projects-in-git-with-different-emails/40124751?noredirect=1#comment67577937_40124751) by the [OP javailike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7000694/javailike), If the url is an ssh one with a passphrase:

```
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Comment: eventhough i did it, its not working for me, when i changed and try to see the changes using git config --list, its not changing

Comment: $ git config user.email xyz@gmail.com
warning: user.email has multiple values
error: cannot overwrite multiple values with a single value
       Use a regexp, --add or --replace-all to change user.email.

Comment: @javailike sure you need to do that command inside your new repo, where you did not set previously an email. But if you did, simply edit it with git config --local --edit.

Comment: Thanks, i have changed using git config --replace-all user.email zyz@gmail.com

Comment: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: eval "$(ssh-agent -s)" and ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa helped me to solve his problem

Comment: @javailike Great! I have completed the answer with your different findings for more visibility.

Answer (score 1):

You could set up different user name and email for this repository only. These settings will override global settings. All you have to do is this:

```
cd <working directory path>
git config --local user.email "xyz@gmail.com"
git config --local user.name "xyz"
```

This will update repository's `.git/config` file. Note, that `--local` is the default behavior, so you can omit `--local`.

You can view your config with:

```
git config --list --show-origin
```

`show-origin` shows where the settings are defined. See [git-config docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) for details.

Comment: If the name remains the same, you don't need to set it locally, as I mention in my answer.

Comment: @VonC You are right, but it also typical for different organizations to demand different user name format (e.g. first/last names order). So I listed it as well, to illustrate that it also could be changed.

Comment: Sure, I just wanted to make clear I posted the local config first ;)